# onLongPressClickListner Child Swipe not showing in android

Tags: android, onlongclicklistener

Hi in the below code cardview long press want to disallow the parent touch event and want to show the swipe edit and share option want to pullout from right.Below code contains a cardview and right side contains edit/share.

When I am long press the cardview from parent I was not allowed horizontal scrollview and but with my below code swipe options are not showing.

```
 holder.cardView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                holder.sample1.setShowMode(SwipeLayout.ShowMode.PullOut);
                holder.sample1.setDragEdge(SwipeLayout.DragEdge.Right);
                   v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);


                return true;
            }
        });
```

layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/back_blue"
    android:id="@+id/contact_card"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/card_details">



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/cards"
                android:background="@color/back_blue">

                <com.daimajia.swipe.SwipeLayout
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/sample1">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/bottom_wrapper"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:weightSum="4"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/share"
                        android:src="@drawable/share"
                        android:layout_width="70dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:background="@color/back_blue"
                        android:paddingRight="15dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:background="@color/slivergray"
                        android:layout_below="@id/share"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/edit"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                        android:layout_width="70dp"
                        android:background="@color/back_blue"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                        android:paddingRight="15dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/cardView"
                    android:layout_width="350dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/slivergray"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                    app:cardElevation="4dp"
                    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:background="@color/White">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/potential_name"
                            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/names"
                            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="3sp"
                            android:text="Potential Name"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:paddingRight="16dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/gray"
                            android:textSize="18sp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/account_name"
                            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/potential_name"
                            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                            android:text="Account Name"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:paddingRight="16dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/gray"
                            android:textSize="15sp"/>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:id="@+id/assigned"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/account_name"
                            android:weightSum="3">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/text_ass"
                                style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/bill_city"
                                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                                android:text="Assigned"
                                android:textColor="@color/gray"
                                android:textSize="15sp" />
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/assigned_to"
                                style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/text_spec"
                                android:layout_weight="2"
                                android:textColor="@color/gray"
                                android:textSize="15sp"/>

                        </LinearLayout>


                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:id="@+id/streets"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/assigned"
                            android:weightSum="3">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/text_spec"
                                style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/bill_city"
                                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                                android:text="Contact"
                                android:textColor="@color/gray"
                                android:textSize="15sp" />
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/contact_name"
                                style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/text_spec"
                                android:layout_weight="2"
                                android:textColor="@color/gray"
                                android:textSize="15sp"/>

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:id="@+id/citys"
                            android:weightSum="3"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/streets">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/text_city"
                                style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/citys"
                                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                                android:text="Location"
                                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:textColor="@color/gray"
                                android:textSize="15sp"
                                />
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/location"
                                style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/text_city"
                                android:layout_weight="2"
                                android:textColor="@color/gray"
                                android:textSize="15sp"/>

                        </LinearLayout>


                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:id="@+id/items"
                            android:weightSum="3"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/citys">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/text_district"
                                style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/bill_district"
                                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                                android:text="Product"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:textColor="@color/gray"
                                android:textSize="15sp" />
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/item_name"
                                style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/text_district"
                                android:layout_weight="2"
                                android:text="product"
                                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                                android:textColor="@color/gray"
                                android:textSize="15sp"/>
                        </LinearLayout>


                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:id="@+id/amounts"
                            android:weightSum="3"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/items"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/text_total"
                                style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/bill_district"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="Value(Qty)"
                                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                                android:textColor="@color/gray"
                                android:textSize="15sp"
                                />
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:weightSum="3"
                                android:paddingLeft="2dp">
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/amount"
                                style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/text_total"
                                android:text="@string/Rs"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:textColor="@color/gray"
                                android:textSize="15sp"/>

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/text_qty"
                                style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/salutations"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="qty"
                                android:textColor="@color/gray"
                                android:textSize="15sp"
                                />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/win_prob"
                                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="30%"
                                    android:textColor="@color/White"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                    />

                            </LinearLayout>


                        </LinearLayout>



                        <View
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="2dp"
                            android:background="@color/slivergray"
                            android:layout_below="@id/amounts"/>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:weightSum="2"
                            android:layout_below="@id/amounts">


                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/potential_no"
                                    style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_below="@+id/account_name"
                                    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                                    android:text="Potenial No."
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:textStyle="bold"
                                    android:textColor="@color/gray"
                                    android:textSize="15sp"/>
                                <Button
                                    android:id="@+id/pdf"
                                    style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="View QUOTE"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:inputType="text"
                                    android:textColor="@color/password"
                                    android:textSize="15sp"
                                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                            </LinearLayout>
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                </com.daimajia.swipe.SwipeLayout>



            </LinearLayout>



        </LinearLayout>


    </FrameLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```